# Laravel Namespacing Path in The View

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I was wondering is it bad practice to be doing this in our views?

```html
@foreach(Session::get('cart') as $item)
  {{\App\Product::find($item)}}
@endforeach
```

Should the controller be doing this work and then passing the data back to the view or is it okay to just handle this in the view? Any best practice advice?

Comment: You should be doing this in the controller and passing the App\Product model to the view from there.

Answer (score 2):

It's data related logic, so the best place for it is a Model. You also can do this in a Controller, but I'd never use data related logic in a view. It's definitely a bad practice.

You're making your app hard to maintain and if you'll want to change something in a future, you'll have to do a lot of work finding and fixing all similar logic all over your views.